# Pass/share parameter values between dependant builds in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.1

**Setup:** `Build CD` has has Artifact Dependency and Snapshot Dependency on `Build CI`. `Build CI` pulls from VCS root and generates artifacts for `Build CD`.

**Problem:** In `Build CD` I need `%teamcity.build.branch%` parameter, but it's not available, because it only uses artifacts and has no VCS Roots linked.

**Question:** Is there a way to pass parameters between dependant builds? (search results in the googles seem of topic)

**Workaround 1:** I can access `%teamcity.build.branch%` in `Build CD` if I link it to same VCS root `Build CI` is using, but I'd like to avoid having this link and `Build CD` unnecessarily pulling from VCS (build log shows it does this).

**Workaround 2:** I could write parameter to a file in `Build CI` and read from it in `Build CD` later. This is a hack and I would like to avoid it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. In `CD`, add a parameter called whatever, with value equal to `%dep.Build_CI.teamcity.build.branch%`. TeamCity will help you figure out the exact value thanks to its auto-suggestion/auto-completion, once you type `%dep.`.

Comment: For some reason TC did not suggest a thing about `%dep.`, but it this did work. Thanks!